# Join query on OLAP and operations data

Tags: analytics, data-warehouse, olap, oltp

I manage in my database a list of tools with this schema:

```
[id] int PRIMARY
[name] varchar
```

Every few seconds each tool emits a measurement. I will save it in an OLAP store with this schema:

```
[toolID] int
[time] timestamp
[measurement] int
```

(We have not chosen the OLAP store yet but assume we need one due to data amounts, semantics, and types of queries we will run)

How do I query the list of tool names with measurements greater than 100? The challenge is that I need to join data from both OLAP and OLTP stores.

**Option 1** - save in OLAP also the tool name with each measurement (denormalization). The problem is the tool name might have changed since the measurement and I need the latest. Also there may be many more details (and detail data) per tool, not sure if it make sense to save it all per measurement.

**Option 2** - OLAP returns just list of IDs, then I issue a query to OLTP to get names. This would require SQL queries with many embedded IDs and seems not right.

**Option 3** - Synchronize all OLTP data into OLAP every few minutes. But OLAP tools are not optimized for updates (e.g. Vertica) so this does not seem efficient.

Comment: Do you literally mean measurement>100 or count(measurement)>100? How big is your list of tools compared to the number of measurement records (percentage)? Does the list of tools and their details really change every few minutes? If a detail changes for a tool, do you want old measurement data to be associated with the old detail, the new detail, or both?

Comment: "4 out of last 6 measurements > 100". each tool will have thousands of measurements. list of tools does not change that often but when it does it is important to show updated data in reports. when details change, old measurements should link to the new details. I guess I'm asking a basic question in datawarehouse here. Do I need to periodically copy all "tools" data rows to the warehouse (where measurments are saved) so joins are easier? I was reading that Vertica does not excel in updates, isn't this periodical copy such an update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, in OLAP/DW systems, **option 3** is preferred and the list of tools and their details would be stored in a Tool dimension table and the measurements would be stored in a Measurement fact table.

If, as you mentioned in your comment, you're **not concerned with saving the history** of a tool's details when the details change and **the frequency as well as the number of updates to the tool details is small**, then I would just update the records in the Tool dimension since it will be a relatively small number of updates.

If the frequency of updates is small but the actual number of updates is large then it may be easier and faster to simply truncate the Tool dimension and insert all Tool records from the OLTP system. In this case, you would need to ensure that there is a way to preserve the dimension keys in order to join back to the fact measurements that have already been stored. This could be difficult if you are using a surrogate key based on an auto-generated sequence.

The real problem arises when the frequency and number of updates to the tool details is large. In this case, you would have to step back and look at the overall model and determine if the tool details actually belong in a dimension or if they deserve their own fact table.

Comment: thanks. If I truncate the Tool dimention, then Tools and Measurments are not in the same DB, so plain joins will be impossible. In this case I need to take all ids I got from the fact and query their data separately from OLTP, using a (long) concatenation of an SQL or a more clever mechanism (SP). Is this right? Also if I do care about saving the tool (and its details) history then I need to add one dimension row (with current tool state) per one fact row?

Comment: In traditional OLAP/DW all the data would be in the same database. If you wanted to truncate instead of update then you would need a good way to re-generate the dimension keys correctly so that they can be joined back to the fact data that has already been stored. For example, if there is a unique TOOL_ID column in the OLTP system then you could use this as the dimension key because it would always be available to copy from the OLTP system to the OLAP system after truncating.

Comment: If you want to keep the tool history then you would not need to update or truncate you could simply insert. This is called a Type II Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD) [Part 1](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/08/21/slowly-changing-dimensions/) and [Part 2](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/09/22/slowly-changing-dimensions-part-2/) of this article describe SCD types and their trade-offs.